# Difference between String.scan and String.split

Tags: ruby

What is the difference between these two (`String#scan` and `String#split`) in Ruby?

Comment: What is the difference? The only thing that they have in common is that they are both called from a `String` object or child class. What seemed so confusing? This question could have just been solved by taking a look at the ruby doc.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They serve entirely different purposes.  [`String#scan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-scan) is used to extract matches of a regular expression from a string and return the matches in an array, while [`String#split`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split) is intended to split a string up into an array, based on a delimiter. The delimiter may be either a static string (like `;` to split on a single semicolon) or a regular expression (like `/\s/+` to split on any whitespace characters).

The output of `String#split` doesn't include the delimiter. Rather, everything except the delimiter would be returned in the output array, while the output of `String#scan` would *only* include what is matched by the delimiter.

```
# A delimited string split on | returns everything surrounding the | delimiters
"a|delimited|string".split("|")
# Prints: ["a", "delimited", "string"]

# The same string scanninng for | only returns the matched |
"a|delimited|string".scan("|")
# Prints: ["|", "|"]
```

Both of the above would also accept a regular expression in place of the simple string `"|"`.

```
# Split on everything between and including two t's
"a|delimited|string".split(/t.+t/)
# Prints: ["a|delimi", "ring"]

# Search for everything between and including two t's
"a|delimited|string".scan(/t.+t/)
# Prints: ["ted|st"]
```

Comment: which one is efficient with respect of performance.

Comment: It is difficult to compare their performance because they are used for different purposes.

Comment: The 2 methods can and sometimes are used for the same general purpose when using ```capture groups``` and can therefore be compared for performance in those situations.